# PHP or shorthand for empty variable

Tags: php

```
$a = '';
$b = 1;
```

How to print $b if $a = '' using shorthand in PHP?

in javascript there is something like

```
a || b;
```

Answer (score 6):

[Ternary Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

```
$a = '';
$b = 1;

echo $a ?: $b; // 1
```

Until $a is evaluated false, $b will be displayed. Remember that the following things are considered to be [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php):

```
"" (an empty string)
0 (0 as an integer)
0.0 (0 as a float)
"0" (0 as a string)
NULL
FALSE
array() (an empty array)
$var; (a variable declared, but without a value)
```

That means that if $a is "", 0, "0", null, false, array(), .. then $b will be displayed. See [PHP type comparison tables](http://php.net/manual/it/types.comparisons.php).

If you want to display $b only when $a is an empty string, then you should uses strict comparison operators (===)

```
$a = '';
$b = 1;

echo $a === '' ? $b : ''; // 1
```

Comment: could this works without echo, e.g I want to change value of variable if its previous value is empty.

Answer (score 1):

This is the shorthand for an `IF/Else` statement in PHP.

```
echo ($a != '' ? $a : $b)
```

If `$a` is not an empty string output (echo) `$a` otherwise output $b.

Answer (score 0):

As others ahve said Turnary operator is handy for most senarios.

```
echo $a ?: $b;//b
```

But it is NOT shorthand for empty().
Ternary operator will issue notices if var/array keys/properties are not set.

```
echo $someArray['key that doesnt exist'] ?: $b;//Notice: Undefined index
echo $arrayThatDoesntExist['key-that-doesnt-exist'] ?: $b;//Notice: Undefined variable
```

empty() will take care of the additional checks for you and its recomended to just use it.

```
if (empty($arrayThatDoesntExist['key-that-doesnt-exist'])) echo $b;
```

You could technically just suppress the warning/notice with @ and the ternary operator becomes a replacement for empty().

```
@echo $someArray['key that doesnt exist'] ?: $b;
@echo $arrayThatDoesntExist['key-that-doesnt-exist'] ?: $b;
```

But usually not recommended as supressing notices and warnings could lead you into trouble later on plus I think it may have some performance impact.